# Changed my NS record in Route53 to point to wix's NS, but now want to revert ... how do I find the original NS values?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

My domain is registered with Route53. I have a wix website, which I'm using as my SaaS app's landing page. I will have a subdomain for my SaaS application app.mywebsite.com. My plan will be to use an A record to point to a S3 bucket to serve the actual SaaS JS application.

Wix told me that to link to my wix site from route53 I should change my NS servers to theirs. So I did. It's taking it's sweet ass time and after some more reading, given I want to do a bunch of DNS configurations (e.g. the A record for JS application, MX and TXT records), I should have used an A record to point to my wix website. Granted I could be wrong on this, but I don't know what the full ramifications are of having wix 'hosting my DNS'.

So I want to revert the NS record to what it was when Amazon created it for me/default. Problem is, I don't know what my original NS servers were on Route53. Is there any way to find them out?

For my own understanding, what is really happening when I edit the NS records?  When I change the NS records in route53, does Amazon submit to some root/authoritative name servers meaning if  someone attempts to access mywebsite.com, go to these (name) servers and they will know exactly where my website is located?

Thanks

Comment: "does Amazon submit to some root/authoritative name servers" only a registrar has access to the relevant registry to push nameservers changes so that they are published on registry authoritative nameservers. Only single DNS hoster can not do it, except if it is the registrar also for the domain (separate jobs but many companies do both)

Answer (score 3):

The "original" nameservers don't matter. What matters is the nameservers for wherever you want to host your DNS. If that's Route 53 you will [find them in your hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html). Otherwise get them from your desired DNS provider.

Comment: so, i found my what I believe-to-be my original name servers in hosted zones, if you expand hosted zones, they will be listed under name servers (at least in the UI at the time of writing). i then replaced my NS record value with these again, and used CNAME and A records to point to my wix site.